# Serialize Object to to Application Settings in C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, appsettings

I am trying to serialize an object into Application Settings.  I have a setting defined to be the object type already.  Here is the class I am trying to serialize.  I have to serialize an object to the application settings because the object type isn't known at runtime.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(TemplateGeneratorPreferences))]
public class MyPreferences
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="GeneratorPreferences", Type=typeof(TemplateGeneratorPreferences))]
    public TemplateGeneratorPreferences FormSpecificPref{ get; set; }

    public MyPreferences()
    {
        GeneratorPreferences = new ScenarioTemplateGeneratorPreferences();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TemplateGeneratorPreferences
{
    [XmlAttribute("MyBool")]
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }

    public ScenarioTemplateGeneratorPreferences()
    {
        MyBool = true;
    }
}
```

This simply won't serialize, I get the follow exception:

> "The type MyPreferences was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude 
>   attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

I included the XmlInclude attribute so I'm a little stumped.

Comment: Adding `[Serializable]` is not necessary when using Xml Serialization in .NET.  Using it the way you do can be misleading, as people will assume it does something or is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx) (the first link that pops up in google when searching for your errormessage) tells you that it's only the base type that needs be augmented with the attribute.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude( typeof( Derived ) )]
public class Base
{
    // ...
}
```

Attaching the XmlInclude attribute allows the XmlSerializer to serialize fields referencing objects of Derived type when a field or property is defined as type Base.

Comment: Already looked at that (yes I know how to use google), I thought adding XmlInclude to the types would help.  With or without XmlInclude I am getting the same exception.  That document only has that 1 particular example for getting this exception.  I am getting this exception pointing to the top level class, not one of the types I am using within it

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code you use to serialize into app settings?

The problem does not appear to be with the types you've defined.  When I do it I get a successful serialization:

```
<MyPreferences 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <GeneratorPreferences MyBool="true" />
</MyPreferences>
```

For classes defined like this:

```
public class MyPreferences
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="GeneratorPreferences")]
    public TemplateGeneratorPreferences FormSpecificPref { get; set; }

    public MyPreferences()
    {
        FormSpecificPref = new TemplateGeneratorPreferences();
    }
}

public class TemplateGeneratorPreferences
{
    [XmlAttribute("MyBool")]
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }

    public TemplateGeneratorPreferences()
    {
        MyBool = true;
    }
}
```

and serialization code like this:

```
    var m = new MyPreferences();
    var s1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyPreferences));
    s1.Serialize(Console.Out, m);
```

Note: you do not need the `[Serializable]` attribute on classes that will be run through the Xml Serializer.